# multiple if scenarios when submitting form

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am trying to add multiple scenarios for when my site visitor submits a form. Right now we have 4 dropdown questions. There will be 3 scenarios:

1. Answer all 4 yes, get redirected to **success** page.
2. Answer any of the questions no, get redirected to **did not qualify** page.
3. Answer the military question **yes** no matter what the other answers are and be redirected **success** page.

Unfortunately, I can't get the 3rd scenario working. Code is below:

```
mail($to, $mailsubject, $body, $header);
if($Q1=='yes' && $Q2=='yes' && $Q3=='yes' && $Q4=='yes'){
    header('Location: http://example.com/success.php'); 
}
if($Q3=='yes'){
    header('Location: http://example.com/success.php'); 
}   

if($Q1=='no' || $Q2=='no' || $Q3=='no' || $Q4=='no' ){
    header('Location: http://example.com/resources.php'); 
}
```

Comment: From a logic standpoint, I believe this could be simplified to check only if military is yes or no.  Might make it easier for you since it would just be an if-else scenario then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($Q3 == "yes") {
    header('Location: http://example.com/success.php');
} else {
    header('Location: http://example.com/resources.php');
}
```

If i am not mistaken, this actually covers all your cases.
Q3 must be yes for both success cases. if it is, nothing else matters. if it's not, it's always a fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($Q3 == "yes")||($Q1=='yes' && $Q2=='yes' && $Q3=='yes' && $Q4=='yes')) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/success.php');
} else {
    header('Location: http://example.com/resources.php');
}
```